# Output InnerHTML Perl LibXML

Tags: html, perl, xpath

Please see MWE below

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $content = "<tr>
                <td class='title'>Synonym(s)</td>
                <td>Automobile<br/>Car<br/></td>
                </tr>";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new({suppress_errors=>1, suppress_warnings=>1,     recover=>2});
my $document = $parser->parse_html_string($content);
my @node = $document->findnodes('//td[@class="title" and text()="Synonym(s)"]/following-sibling::td');
print $node[0]->toString();
```

The output is:
`<td>Automobile<br/>Car<br/></td>`

But I need just the "inner" content:
`Automobile<br/>Car<br/>`

How do I need to change the xPath, or do I need a different LibXML method.

Thank you,
Tobias

Comment: Well, there `textContent` to spit out the text. That'll strip the `<BR>` tags though, which are treated as part of the XML.

Comment: `my @nodes = ...;` is better written as `my ($node) = ...;` if you just want the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do that in XML::LibXML. Changing the xpath won't help. That xpath gives you a list of `td` elements. If you'd get the stuff inside of all `td` elements that fit the current xpath, you'd end up with a long list of things and no way to discern where the content of the first `td` ends and the second `td` starts.

Instead, you need to construct it by converting [all children](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod#childNodes) of the `td` element to string.

```
print join '', map { $_->toString } $node[0]->childNodes;
```

Output:

```
Automobile<br/>Car<br/>
```